# Grant all on procedures to user

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

When i execute the following Statement by substituting object_type to table [OBJECT_TYPE='TABLE'], it executes successfully, by when i try it to procedure like the following, it returns error: table or view does not exit.

```
BEGIN
   FOR R IN (SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE owner = 'MY_SCHEMA' AND OBJECT_TYPE='PROCEDURE') LOOP
      execute IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON '|| R.OWNER ||'.'||R.OBJECT_NAME ||' TO MyUser';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Note: when i also try to execute as single statement it runs successfully.

```
GRANT ALL ON MY_SCHEMA.ProcedureName TO MyUser;
```

So what is difference, and why does not work on procedures.

Comment: I've removed the multiple RDBMS tags here; it's clearly not t-sql, but please update your post with the correct one.

Comment: Why not grant your permissions to the entire schema?

Comment: I want to grant all permissions of schema A of user to an other user schema B and there no way grant all the permissions in one statement except by granting all table or procedures then creating synonyms of all objects. @dan-bracuk

Comment: Works fine for me. Does this fail at the first procedure in the list, or does it get some way before failing? If there is one that fails where others succeed, you need to find out what's different about it. I suspect some namespace clash (e.g. a public synonym happens to share the same name as a procedure) although I can't think of any scenario that would fail like this.

Answer (score 0):

try to show all the statements and then run all of them. one of it will definitely give you that error!

Try this:

```
SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR R IN
  (SELECT OWNER,
    OBJECT_NAME
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
  WHERE owner    = 'MY_SCHEMA'
  AND OBJECT_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
  )
  LOOP
    v_sql:= 'GRANT ALL ON '|| R.OWNER ||'.'||R.OBJECT_NAME ||' TO MyUser';
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

and then run all those statements, in order to find the exact statement that gives you error.

Comment: Yes, that's good idea and i tested, it is not different from executing as one statement and there no error. and still wondering why on single statement and not on loop. thanks.

Comment: hmmm .. I'm speechless  :)

Comment: Perhaps there is no error because is only prints the GRANT statements . How about putting back the `execute immediate`?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, he prints the statements and then run all of them by hand and there is no error .. but when he execute them, gives error ..